# Laravel Error: Class App\Models\Signatories does not exist after Renaming it to Signatory

Tags: php, laravel-5

Good Day .. I have a model that I want to rename from **Signatories** to **Signatory** but after I run composer dump-autoload or composer dump-autoload -o it says :

```
In Container.php line 826: Class App\Models\Signatories does not exist
```

I've tried running php artisan clear-compile, and I've got thesame error.

Here's my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Kyslik\ColumnSortable\Sortable;

class Signatory extends Model{

    use Sortable;

    protected $table = 'signatories';

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    public $sortable = ['employee_name', 'employee_position', 'type'];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

I've also rename the file .. 
Can someone understand this error ??

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Try to search the use cases of `Signatories` in your project. Search in project with a good editor/ide.

Comment: Meeeen .. I solved it .. thank you for your suggestion .. I've just search those files and find out not renaming one of the dependencies .. thanks bro ..

Comment: Glad to know that, most welcome :-)